# Starting with Kinect for Windows - SDK 1.7

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm starting with Kinect SDK 1.7, using KinectRegion and other controls like KinectTileButton and KinectScrollViewer from the toolkit. My questions are:

- How to enable KinectRegion to work with left and right hands?
- Does the SDK 1.7 have something ready to work with zooming?
- How to detect grip and release?
- Any code available on the Internet?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. To Enable the Kinect Region :

   - Import "Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls" project into your solution. (Use **Add** -> **Existing Project**)
   - Add Reference of "Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls" into your project.
   - Add KinectRegion into your XAML using this code :

     [image]
   - Import/Use "Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls" in your xaml.cs file :

   using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit;

   - Bind the sensor chooser's current sensor to the KinectRegion :

   var regionSensorBinding = new Binding("Kinect") { Source = this.sensorChooser };
   BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.kinectRegion, KinectRegion.KinectSensorProperty,
   regionSensorBinding);
2. I don't get what you mean about "zooming". Please give more detail.
3. To detect hand gripping and hand release, you can add "AddHandPointerGripHandler" and "AddHandPointerGripReleaseHandler" to your KinectRegion. Please take a look to the KinectScrollViewer.cs.
4. You can explore the code about the hand pointer and stuff from the "Kinect Developer Toolkit Browser App".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, KinectRegion works with both hand and automatically detects which one is the main one.
The grip and release detection is also automatic on KinectScrollViewer controls.
About the zooming I have no idea.

You'll find good tutorial on Kinect SDK 1.7 Interactions features on [this link](http://www.soulsolutions.com.au/Blog/tabid/73/EntryId/851/Kinect-For-Windows-Interactions-Gallery.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how to show both hands at the same time using KinectRegion?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely outstanding course is on the links below:

The [first part](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2013/03/25/kinect-interactions-with-wpf-part-i-getting-started.aspx) shows the basic of Kinect SDK

The second part is similiar to firs part, but with use of MS Blend

And [the third part](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2013/05/03/kinect-interactions-with-wpf-part-iii-demystifying-the-interaction-stream.aspx) is tutorial for interaction stream, where you can get information of both hands.

But if you´d like to use both hand at Kinect region, you have to edit Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls -> KinectRegion.cs -> line 1000 (more info in [MSDN Blog question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e00d05d-8b97-4838-b3d6-76a71c4d3166/how-to-use-two-hand-cursors-simultaneously-using-kinect-interactions))

It helped to me! (I have the same problem)!

For Grip detection is available in *kinectRegion -> kinectRegion.HandPointers[idex of hand(0 is left, 1 is right)].IsInGripInteraction* - it´s bool - I added some code:

```
private Skeleton []skeleton;

private void kinect_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {

            using (SkeletonFrame sf = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (sf != null && this.skeleton != null) // check that a frame is available
                {
                    sf.CopySkeletonDataTo(this.skeleton); // get the skeletal information in this frame

                }
            }

        }

sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += new EventHandler<SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs>(kinect_SkeletonFrameReady);

foreach (var sk in skeleton)
        {
          if (sk.TrackingId == 0) continue;
          else
          {
             if (kinectRegion.HandPointers[0].IsInGripInteraction == true)
             {
                .......
             }
          }
        }
```